# How to view firebase object in a table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase table of doctors and I want to show it in a html table. I already do that in console but can't show it in html. I tried using createElement() but it shows error. My code is bellow

```
var ref=database.ref('doctors');
  ref.on('value',getData, errData);

  function getData(data){
    //console.log(data.val());
    var doctors=data.val();
    var keys=Object.keys(doctors);
    console.log(keys);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var k=keys[i];
        var designation=doctors[k].designation;
        var doctor_email=doctors[k].doctor_email;
        var doctor_id=doctors[k].doctor_id;
        var doctor_phone=doctors[k].doctor_phone;
        var hospital_id=doctors[k].hospital_id;
        var isApproved=doctors[k].isApproved;
        var name=doctors[k].name;
        var specialization=doctors[k].specialization;
        var token=doctors[k].token;

       console.log(designation,doctor_email,doctor_id,doctor_phone,hospital_id,isApproved,name,specialization,token)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a single div with an id `div_output` for example, and use it to build your table as shown below:

```
var output = document.getElementById("div_output");
output.innerHTML = "<table>";    // clearing any previous html content
                                 // and setting up header row
output.innerHTML += "<tr>"       
                            + "<th> Designation </th>"
                            + "<th> E-Mail </th>"
                            + "<th> ID </th>"
                            + "<th> Phone </th>"
                            + "<th> Hospital ID </th>"
                            + "<th> Approved? </th>"
                            + "<th> Name </th>"
                            + "<th> Specialization </th>"
                            + "<th> Token </th>"
                          + "</tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k=keys[i];
    var designation=doctors[k].designation;
    var doctor_email=doctors[k].doctor_email;
    var doctor_id=doctors[k].doctor_id;
    var doctor_phone=doctors[k].doctor_phone;
    var hospital_id=doctors[k].hospital_id;
    var isApproved=doctors[k].isApproved;
    var name=doctors[k].name;
    var specialization=doctors[k].specialization;
    var token=doctors[k].token;
                                     // appending doctor's row of data
    output.innerHTML += "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + designation + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + doctor_email+ "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + doctor_id+ "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + doctor_phone+ "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + hospital_id+ "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + isApproved + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + name + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + specialization + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + token + "</td>"
                      + "</tr>";

}

output.innerHTML += "</table>";  //closing the table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You are a life saver. :)